# Get Regex from Dictionary - Python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have made a lot of simple regular expressions, and I have a text to search with them. So, basically, I decided to make them into a dictionary and tuck the match counts as values into another dictionary with respective keys:

```
dic={"left":re.compile("[Лл]ев"),"right":re.compile("[Пп]рав")}
def counter(reg, text):
    cntr = 0
    for line in text:
        cntr += len(re.findall(reg, line))
    return cntr

def regdict(dicc, source):
    k = {}
    for key in dicc:
        k[key]=counter(dicc[key], source)
    return k
regdict(dic,text)
```

the result is either the right count of one regex with 0 for another or a `{'right': 0, 'left': 0}`, and it changes with every run. I dont understand what is wrong, the first function works fine.

Comment: what is text in `regdict(dic,text)`?  is it a file opened in read mode, or is it a list?

Comment: use `print()` to see what values you have in functions. It helps to find problem.

Comment: as @miah suggest - if you use single string as `text` then `for line in text:` will assign single char to `line`. BTW. I found this problem because I used `print()` to display values in variables.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that if it is a file object iterator, then unless it is reset between loops, the second time you try to read it, it will still be at the end.

Comment: @furas @miah the text is a multiline UTF-8  `text = open('listbycolumn.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`. The prints I deletedfor public convenince show that it inly accumulates matches for one of the keys

Comment: use more `print()` to see all values in variables and what is going on in code - it helps to find where is real problem. Or learn how to use debuger.